Has the whole world become Mleccha in this Kaliyuga?
We all know what happened in our history.
Mughals came, ruled for 600 years killed millions of Hindus, Destroyed Temples, then came the Britishers, they also killed millions of Hindus, and spread the western cultural Influence here.
in modern India of today, there are crores of Mleechas of a certain peaceful community with a 15% of total population living in our country, the fact that the so called Hindus even tolerate this is a dosha itself. Even the majority of Hindu people, a Huge amount of them are engaged in some sort of sinful and wrong activities as expected of Kaliyuga.
Has our Āryāvarta truly become a Mleccha Dasha itself?
Because the way things have happened and the way it virtually destroyed the original vedic culture. I don't think we live in the real Āryāvarta anymore.
Considering that it wouldn't be wrong to declare that all of the world has become majority of Mleechas.
Before i started gaining the knowledge of Vedas and shastras, i used to have a wish to go to a foreign country for better life.
But now even though there may be a wish within my heart, as a wise person i mustn't follow these desires, but then the thought that pretty much whole world has become full of Mleechas everywhere, would it even matter if I were to live on the other side of the world or stay in india?

@Aryan I do not think the whole of India has become mlecchafied. Sanatan dharma and the varnashrama dharma are declining in Bharat but they are still there in noticeable proportions. That Aryavrata has shrunk is seen when we look at your profile picture and compare with the present day borders :)

I think, in Puranas, it is mentioned that in Kaliyuga shudras will rule aryavarta.

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay Very true. For instance, the Shrimad Bhagavatam mentions a time King Parikshit encountered the Kalipurusha who was in the form of a shudra wearing the attire of kings and beating two cows.

Note: References will be provided/added only on request or whenever I feel like as I have to find the chapter and verses in the Bhavishya Purana all over again.
According to the Bhavishya Purana, the Mlecchas that you see today have come from the mud in Lord Narayana's feet at the behest of Kalipurusha. Most of the Mlechhas were wiped out in the Mlechhasatra of King Mlecchahanta towards the end of Dwaparyuga. So, Kalipurusha requested a replenishment of the Mlecchas which Lord Narayana granted. So the Mlechhas of today have the distinction of having their lineage directly from Lord Narayana Himself.
But since they were requested by Kalipurusha all Mlechhas are by default agents of the Kalipurusha and in the Kalyuga their increased numbers is expected. Bhavishya Puran also mentions the coming of the Mlechhas into the Aryavrata but they will be driven out in about 200 years from now when China becomes a Hindu nation due to the Vayudeva's incarnation somewhere in China and His children taking over.
